# QWidget within scrollarea

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QWidget` that I want to include within a scroll-area so that when the designated `QWidget` size is exceeded vertically, the user can scroll up and down to see more.

```
QWidget renameWidget;
QScrollArea scrollarea.
```

How do I go about doing this? I set the widget inside the scroll-area on the UI editor but it didn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Think of [QScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) as another layout. Add the scroll area to your main widget and put everything else inside it with [setWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget).

`QScrollArea` is `QWidget`, so you can even use it as a top level widget:

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
scrollArea->resize(250, 250);

QWidget *widget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
widget->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
widget->resize(200, 200);

scrollArea->setWidget(widget);
scrollArea->show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`QScrollArea` provides a scrolling view onto another widget. It is used to display the contents of a child widget within a frame. If the widget exceeds the size of the frame, the view can provide scroll bars so that the entire area of the child widget can be viewed.

An example:

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollArea->setWidget(renameWidget);
```